# Searching for Rackmount hardware - raspberry pi 2 performance lookalike

Tags: linux, router, raspberry-pi, ubuntu

I am looking for a hardware which can be mounted into a rack.
There is no specific performance requirements:

- min 1GB RAM
- ARM64 or x86 based architecture

A normal Ubuntu Core with a small JAVA applet should be run.

Interfaces:

- 2-4 I/O ports

Network connectivity:

- Ethernet (1 G is better, but 100 Mbps is acceptable)
- 3G/4G modem

a NTH feature to reach 70 degree in operating temperature. Do you have any suggestion? Thank you for your help!